# Importing a RSS feed from a Sharepoint subsite blog to the main page

Tags: blog, rss

I can not get the rss feed to work, when trying I get the error message:

> Forbidden.

I have already done a lot of research around this and tried Xml without any result. Worth mentioning is that any external RSS works perfectly fine.

My question is simply, is there a way around this? Except for installing kerebros that would be, wich is an option I have found.

I have an idea of perhaps putting the rss from SharePoint on an external site and then pick it up from there to the main page, have anyone attempted this?

Answer (score 0):

Soloved it. Using the Content Query webpart you can import data from your Collection without getting security issues. Cheers.